# Displaying UIImageViews in different UIView with different size

Tags: ios, xcode, uiview, uiimageview

I am displaying `UIImageViews` programmatically. It works fine with the first `UIView` but when I try to display it on the smaller `view`, it does not resize.
Can you help me. Thanks in advance

By the way, I have a custom class of my `UIView` called `courtView`. I use this class for the two `UIView`

```
UIImageView *newImage;
    NSSet *ballPosition = [self.startPosition valueForKey:@"ballPosition"];
    for (BallPosition *courtPosition in ballPosition) {
        PlayerPosition *player = [courtPosition valueForKey:@"playerPosition"];
        if ([player.team  isEqual: @(1)]) {
            newImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Btn_blue.png"]];
        }
        else if ([player.team  isEqual: @(2)]){
            newImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Btn_red.png"]];
        }
        else if ([player.team  isEqual: @(0)]){
            newImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Ball.png"]];
        }
        newImage.frame = CGRectFromString([courtPosition valueForKey:@"courtPosition"]);

        [self.courtView addSubview:newImage];

    }
```

Comment: What you have tried? Show some code.

Comment: Did you resize the frame of imageviews when transition from one view to other. Can you show some code , how it presently works.

Comment: Thanks. i edited my question already. hope it help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this code

```
UIImage *myImage = [UIImage imageNamed :@"myImage.extension"]; 
//if ur images are static, if your images are from an array then loop it out write the below inside the loop, make sure myImageView is a class,static component.
CGFloat height = myImage.size.height;
CGFloat width = myImage.size.width;

myImageView.frame = CGRectMake (myImageView.frame.origin.x,myImageView.frame.origin.y,height,width);
myImageView.image = myImage;
```

Hope this helps